# Why do people downvote my answers on my own questions?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, self-answer, specific-answer, downvote-reason

I asked [Can't write to 64-bit registry using .NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188373/net-c-sharp-64-cant-write-to-registry), and then I found the answer on my own, so I posted it.

I got -2 on my question (though I showed them first one approach I tried to solve my solution, and then I updated my question to add another approach I tried). But the disaster is that I got  **-2** on my answer. Why are people downvoting **my answer**? That answer **works** for me and I shared the solution that works for me.

Comment: I didn't vote on either, but I did add a comment to your answer. As it stands it's just a "here's the code" answer with no context on why it works. Adding an explanation for why something works adds far more value to an answer.

Comment: @DanielKelley if some body asked me what does the additional parameter mean (like u did) i would have explained, but what happened actually is users come down vote and go. simply

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli users aren't required to comment on downvotes. Did you really need more information than the downvotes to know that wasn't a good answer? Put yourself in someone else's shoes, and read it - is it helpful?

Comment: I'd suspect that the lack of explanation is only a small part of the problem.  The bigger part of the problem is that, like this question was before @cupcake got to it, the question and answer looks like it was thrown together without any time spent looking out for grammar spelling and punctuation.

Comment: Downvotes show others' judgement on the quality of your answer. Whether you are happy with your own answer is something else. It is, as you imply, often thought good practice to explain why something is being downvoted. On the other hand, when there is the possibility that someone will overreact to downvoting, some people feel it  is best to register dissatisfaction anonymously. You are then expected to ponder why there was downvoting and to try to improve your answer.  (I played no part in this thread.)

Comment: When you post an answer, you probably don't need any (or need only a little) explanation of the code, since you understand how it works (hopefully!). Now, as jonr mentioned, how about other people? While some people might not care about the reason, the rest (like me) care, and your original post didn't help anything to understand why it works. That's my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people *probably* disagreed with the contents of that answer.
That's literally all we can say about the reason behind those downvotes.

Downvotes don't require a user to explain them. In fact, a user can vote any way he likes, so whatever reason we can give you is nothing but speculation.

My guess would be that the answer is relatively minimal. While it (probably) works, there's only a very limited explanation of what the answer does.

Comment: This boilerplate really needs to go somewhere other than just every meta comment/answer to every "why was my post downvoted?" question :(

Answer (score 11):

Biggest problem I see with this Q+A is that it just doesn't add anything useful to the existing solutions.  The kind you trivially google with a query like "registrykey cannot write the registry key".  Note how the top two hits are MSDN articles, the next two are SO.  Which already cover your problem and answer it *much* better than you did.

So your question got downvoted for not doing the basic research.  Your answer got downvoted because it is a rather poor explanation, it never even mentioned the significance of the *true* argument.

Please delete this Q+A, it is not helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Hans Passant already explained why you should not even have posted the question and why you should delete both the answer and the question.

But you should also notice that even if [Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), some people around think that it could be seen as easy rep farming. My advice is that (like for other posts, but even a little more) you must be sure to make both the question and the answer quality posts. That means (non exclusive list):

- do enough research to make sure it is not a duplicate
- make sure the question is a real on topic question that could be answered by someone else
- make sure the spelling and grammar are not to poor (if english is not your first language, google translate can be your friend)
- make sure the answer could be useful to someone else: explaination on why it was broken, why it will now work and a code example, possibly external reference if relevant

The above should be the rule for any post on SO, and specially on self answers. If you post a new Q+A following above rules and you are downvoted again, come again on meta and the meta effect should give your post what it really deserves: upvotes it Q and A are quality posts but... downvotes if they are not

Comment: Just a side note: the original posts did not follow 3 of my 4 rules...

Answer (score 3):

Downvotes are not necessarily due to the answer being incorrect. In this case, it appears they are because the answer, while factually correct, does not explain itself adequately, and hence does not meet the bar for quality content that is Stack Overflow's goal.